# Simple multiple selection checkbox dropdown that passed variables to the url

Tags: php, jquery

I want to create a very simple (no plugins and basic layout) for a dropdown menu that has checkboxes for options. For example, if C and F are selected and the form is submitted, I want the url to show `/index.php?category1=3&&category2=6`

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <select multiple="multiple" name="category">
        <optgroup label="Category1">
            <option value="1">A</option>
            <option value="2">B</option>
            <option value="3">C</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Category2">
            <option value="4">D</option>
            <option value="5">E</option>
            <option value="6">F</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>

    <br><input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

I am not even sure how to start the jquery to pass the values to the url. Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT:
I figured I can do this using  instead and simulate a dropdown with jquery.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k6R7g/

how can I show "2 Selected" instead of "Select..." when selections are made?

Comment: why do you want to send the URL like that? you can get the desired values in php,even without sending it like that

Comment: because I want to have a unique url for different categories so i can later put on links to each category individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See code below, construct the url yourself and it will work. In case the form contains more values you can better add the category to the value of the option.

```
  <form method="get">
        <select multiple="multiple" name="category">
            <optgroup label="Category1">
                <option value="1">A</option>
                <option value="2">B</option>
                <option value="3">C</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Category2">
                <option value="4">D</option>
                <option value="5">E</option>
                <option value="6">F</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>

        <br><input type="button" value="go" onclick="clicked();">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function clicked(){
        var v = "";
        $('select').find(":selected").each(
            function(){
                if (v != ""){
                    v += "&";
                }
                v += $(this).parent()[0].label + '=' + $(this).context.value; 
                }
            );

        window.location.href = "index.php?" + v;
    }
    </script>
```